# Single Hyphenation Exception

Tags: hyphenation

By default, TeX uses the parameters `\lefthyphenmin=2\righthyphenmin=3` to insert the minimum hyphenation fragments from the left and right. However, there is a single word (and perhaps others) for which I think it may be acceptable to place a hyphenation point at the 2nd character from the right: `LinkedIn` (the professional networking site). I'm wondering if I could automatically insert the hyphenation point `Linked-In` while still keeping the `\righthyphenmin=3` rule for other words. Yes, I know I can type `Linked\-In` using a discretionary hyphen each time I see the word. My question involves setting this hyphenation rule automatically, for example, in a hyphenation library.

Comment: Are you free to use LuaLaTeX to compile your document? If you are, providing the instruction `\hyphenation{linked-in}` in the preamable gets the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're free to use LuaLaTeX to compile your document, simply providing the instruction

```
\hyphenation{linked-in}
```

in the preamble gets the job done.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{1sp} % just for this test document
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\hyphenation{linked-in}

\begin{document}
LinkedIn
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not change the parameters but for such logo names you can define a command

```
\newcommand\linkedin{Linked\-In}
```

That said, I would not hyphenate a name.